Спарсить с iframe отзывы c yandex карты
Вот скрипт который подгружает на сайт отзывы с яндекс карт.
<iframe id="yandFrame" src="https://yandex.ru/maps-reviews-widget/1107562954?comments"></iframe>

В доме внутри iframe есть элемент .comment__name и .comment__text . Нужно с них достать содержимое. То есть имена и тексты отзывов. Вот так не работает
var iBody = $("iframe").contents().find("body");
var myContent = iBody.find(".comment__name").text();
console.log(iBody);

Как это сделать?

API отзывов Яндекса не существует, а любые недокументированные запросы или парсинг считаются нарушением пункта 4.1.2 условий использования, единственный вариант – использовать стандартный виджет в его оригинальном виде, без возможности напрямую работать с данными внутри него.
